# How to upload multiple images to server with progress bar in ionic 2?

Tags: file-upload, camera, angular, ngcordova, ionic2

I need to upload several images to server taken from camera or library and show uploading status using progress bar. I couldn't find any useful resources in Ionic 2.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of progress bars. Ones that show the progress in percentage, and infinite ones that are just letting the user know that an action is completing.

And how you will upload your images on your server is something that you have to think. If you plan to upload them all at once with one post request than you can make an infinite progress bar that is shown before the "upload" starts and hide it when the server responds back (Which means the images are stored on your database).

Another way is: if you MUST show real progress in percentage than you can send each image in a separate request. You can count the number of images that you have, and on every server response you will increase the progress bar by 100/NUMBER_OF_IMAGES. On the last sent image you will hide the progress bar which should be 100% at that time.

P.S: Even on some most sophisticated softwares the progress bars are not 100% accurate. You can get as a reference windows copy/cut folder operation. The ETA is almost never accurate :)

Comment: Thank you Denko, can please share code snippet how this can achieved via Ionic 2?

Comment: could u help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784079/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-on-uploading-a-file @Denko Mancheski